# Kafka Connect Elastic Search Sink Connector support for pushing to alias indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect

I am planning to use a shared index associated with alias indexes to support multi-tenancy for an event monitoring solution. I want to use Kafka Connect ElasticSearch Sink Connector to push events from a Kafka topic to an alias index instead of using the index directly. Does Kafka Connect support such feature currently ?

Comment: I think the better question is if elastic search connector supports this, I would say it does, but I'm not 100%.

Comment: AFAIK i do this in the version 7.0.1 of the kafka connect elasticsearch sink connector. But the problem i am facing is, my indexes have ilm configured. So when i Upsert, the updates don't work on indexes that are not warm. so i end up having duplicates in my index.